# 'Truncated incorrect INTEGER value' error when joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

The error is generated because of the trigger written to the table 'SelektionDatenquelleFelder'.
When I am trying to insert records into the table 'SelektionDatenquelleFelder', I can't add and showing this error. Because a trigger has been written for this table 'SelektionDatenquelleFelder'. How can I solve the problem? It is mentionable that the datatype for table-column is 'SelektionenBenutzerGeteilt.selektionId' is INT.

```
INSERT INTO SelektionDatenquellenBenutzerBerechtigungen(BenutzerId,DatenqulleId,FeldId,Berechtigung,ErfassungBenutzerID,ErfassungZeitstempel)
    SELECT Benutzer.BenutzerID, SelektionDatenquelleFelder.DatenqulleId, SelektionDatenquelleFelder.Id
    ,(CASE WHEN S.BenutzerId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Berechtigungen
    ,Benutzer.ErfassungBenutzerID,NOW()
    FROM SelektionDatenquelleFelder 
    INNER JOIN SelektionDatenquellen ON SelektionDatenquellen.Id = SelektionDatenquelleFelder.DatenqulleId
    CROSS JOIN  Benutzer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SURIS.SelektionenBenutzerGeteilt AS S ON S.SelektionId = CONVERT(RIGHT(SelektionDatenquellen.`Name`,5),UNSIGNED)AND S.BenutzerId = Benutzer.BenutzerID
    WHERE SelektionDatenquelleFelder.Id = NEW.Id;
```

> 13:41:04 INSERT INTO `SURIS_SuRBV`.`SelektionDatenquelleFelder` (`Id`,
>   `DatenqulleId`, `Feldname`, `Anzeige`, `Datentyp`, `Prioritaet`)
>   VALUES ('4036', '2', 'MBNrKundebMB', 'MBNrKundebMB', 'System.String',
>   '170') 1292: Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'unden'

**Table structures**

```
CREATE TABLE `SelektionDatenquelleFelder`
 (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DatenqulleId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Feldname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Anzeige` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Datentyp` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Prioritaet` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `selektiondatenquellefelder_ibfk_1` (`DatenqulleId`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `selektiondatenquellefelder_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DatenqulleId`) REFERENCES `SelektionDatenquellen` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4628 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE `SelektionenBenutzerGeteilt` (
  `SelektionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BenutzerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SelektionId`,`BenutzerId`),
  KEY `BenutzerId` (`BenutzerId`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `selektionenbenutzergeteilt_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SelektionId`) REFERENCES `Selektionen` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: can you share the table structure, seems like there is a conflict in datatype of your insert statement.

Comment: Just run the select portion of the inserts and look for unden

Comment: 'unden' because the data for SelektionDatenquellen.`Name` is 'SelektionSystemDatenquelleKunden' where 5 characters from right side is 'unden'.

Comment: is there a trigger running on this insert in the table `SelektionDatenquellenBenutzerBerechtigungen` as the error is about a other table `SelektionDatenquelleFelder `...

Comment: ... i need coffee it seams you are saying that also ... *"Because a trigger has been written for this table 'SelektionDatenquelleFelder'. How can I solve the problem?"*  You can start by posting that trigger code aswell as the error seams to be related to the trigger..

Comment: Also when people ask you for code you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432112/truncated-incorrect-integer-value-error-when-joining-tables) instead to include that information...Please do not use Google docs..

Comment: Yes, two triggers have been written for timestamp.